# What is difference between below two Conditions?? 1. where ABC>='00' and ABC<='ZZ' 2.where ABC>='0' and ABC<='Z'

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Many of report and Developers team must be using the condition

```
where ABC>='00' and ABC<='ZZ'
```

i.e to select/refer all data from that column. My question is what is difference between below two conditions??

1.

```
where ABC>='00' and ABC<='ZZ'
```

2.

```
where ABC>='0' and ABC<='Z'
```

as I have got different results with these two condition

Comment: Different results with MySQL ior Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: It seems that applying the concept of 'greater than' and 'less than' to string comparisons is bound to cause confusion, if not bugs.

Comment: So, you're looking for a basic primer on how string comparison works?

Comment: Difference is in the `ASCII` values.

Comment: '0' < '00', but 'ZZ' > 'Z'. I guess you should do ABC>='0' and ABC<='ZZ' instead.

Answer (score 1):

'Z' comes before 'ZZ' in a lexiograhic ordering.  So ABC<='Z' exludes more than ABC<='ZZ'

Consider for example the string 'ZA'.  `'ZA'<='ZZ'` is true because 'ZA' would be sorted before 'ZZ'.  But 'ZA' comes after 'Z' in a lexiographic order, so `'ZZ'<='Z'` is false.